# Hipergeometric. Kids and candy.

Tags: probability, statistics

**Problem**

There are $15$ identical bags of candy each containing $20$ yellow, $15$ red, $5$ blue and $10$ green
candies. $15$ children are each given their own candy bag and each randomly
picks $12$ candies from their own bags.

What is the probability that at least two
of the kids will have at least one green candy?

**This what I get so far:**

Each bag contains $N=50$ candies out of which $k=10$ are green. Each child draws $n=12$ times without replacement. Considering the number of "successes", drawing a green candy, this is a Hypergeometric distribution with parameters $N,k,n$.

Therefore, the probability that a child draws at least one candy is

$$1-\frac{40\choose12}{50\choose 12}.$$

Now, I need to calculate the probabilty of two of this 15 kids  will have at least one green candy. I'm stuck here.

---

I show my progress, after the help:

I calculate P(X>=)=1-P(X=0) = 0.9539
Then Y=# of kids with green candy.

P(y>=2)= 1- 15Cn0 p^0 (1-p0)^15 - 15Cn1 p^1 (1-p)^14
      = 1-[(1)(1)(0.0461)^15 - (15 (0.9539) (0.0461)^14]
      = aprox 1

After all this I'm thinking:

**Is that true? The probability of at leat two kids have at least one green candy could be 100%?**

Thanks, for your help community.

Comment: Not 100%, could be approx 100% ! Mind it, the expected # of candies with each child is 3.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, let P(a child has at least one green candy) = $p$, which you have computed.

Now apply binomial$(15,p)$